# How to display always the last day of the week

Tags: java

I have a JSF table which displays activity of users.

```
<p:lineChart id="logins" value="#{StatisticsController.weekActivity}" legendPosition="e"  
                                 title="Weekly Logins" seriesColors="4D94FF, 1975FF, 005CE6, 0047B2" minY="0" maxY="200"/>


public class Statistics implements Serializable {

    private CartesianChartModel weeksActivity;

    public Statistics() {  
        createweeksActivity(); 

    }  

    public CartesianChartModel getweekActivity() {  
        return weeksActivity;  
    }

    private void createweeksActivity() {  
        weeksActivity = new CartesianChartModel();  

        ChartSeries boys = new ChartSeries();  
        boys.setLabel("Active Accounts");  

        boys.set("Monday", 120);  
        boys.set("Tuesday", 100);  
        boys.set("Wednesday", 44);  
        boys.set("Thursday", 150);  
        boys.set("Friday", 120);
        boys.set("Saturday", 82);  
        boys.set("Sunday", 115);  

        ChartSeries girls = new ChartSeries();  
        girls.setLabel("Blocked Accounts");  

        girls.set("Monday", 52);  
        girls.set("Tuesday", 60);  
        girls.set("Wednesday", 110);  
        girls.set("Thursday", 135);  
        girls.set("Friday", 120);
        girls.set("Saturday", 140);  
        girls.set("Saturday", 130);  
        girls.set("Sunday", 140);  

        weeksActivity.addSeries(boys);  
        weeksActivity.addSeries(girls);  
    }  


}
```

I want to display the current day always last in order. For example:
Now I get this order: `Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday`
If for example today is Wednesday I want to get this order when I open the web page:

```
Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday
```

How I can solve this problem?

```
EDIT:
```

I updated the code this way:

```
private void createweeksActivity()
    {

        weeksActivity = new CartesianChartModel();

        ChartSeries activeAccounts = new ChartSeries();
        activeAccounts.setLabel("Active Accounts");

        ChartSeries blockedAccounts = new ChartSeries();
        blockedAccounts.setLabel("Blocked Accounts");

        GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            System.out.println(df.format(calendar.getTime()));
            activeAccounts.set(df.format(calendar.getTime()), getNumberOfLogins(df.format(calendar.getTime())));
            blockedAccounts.set(df.format(calendar.getTime()), getNumberOfLogins(df.format(calendar.getTime())));
        }       

        weeksActivity.addSeries(activeAccounts);
        weeksActivity.addSeries(blockedAccounts);
    }

    public int getNumberOfLogins(String day){

        // Get here the number of logins using SQL command
        // Example: SELECT * FROM HISTORY WHERE DAY = day;

        return 100;
    }
```

I suppose that it will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    System.out.println(df.format(calendar.getTime()));
}
```

A GregorianCalendar represents an instant in time, under our gregorian calendar. Its no-arg constructor initializes it to the current time.

A DateFormat is used to format dates. You can transform a `(Gregorian)Calendar` into a Date using its `getTime()` method. "EEEE" means the day of the week, in its longest form.

The `(Gregorian)Calendar.add()` method allows adding a value to any field of the calendar (year, month, date, hour, etc.). Since you want to iterate through the days of the week, I start from tomorrow, and add 1 day at each iteration.

Everything is available in [the javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/).

Comment: Would you please extend the code a little bit. I'm new to Java. I need a little explanation how I can use this code.

Answer (score 1):

Have your Days of Week as a Map to its DAY OF WEEK number according to Calendar.

Then use Calendar to get the Current Day and use Modular Arithmetic to change the ordering.

Something like:

```
//This you can do it one time and then use it in your program
Map<Integer, String> daysOfWeek = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
daysOfWeek.put(Calendar.MONDAY, "Monday");
daysOfWeek.put(Calendar.TUESDAY, "Tuesday");
//so on and so forth.



//Now the code that will be running 
//You get your current Day  (Which will be the last one you want to see)
int weekday = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

//Start with next value (modulus 7 since you don't want overflow)
int currDay = (weekday+1) % 7;


//Go over the seven Days
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    String currDay = daysOfWeek.get(currDay);  //Get your Day String

    //Here do whatever you need to do to set up the DAY in JSF

    currDay = (currDay+1) % 7;  //Moving currDay to the next Day
 }
```